# Ensuring setInterval does not repeat itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm using Node.js with socket.io and have setInterval for a timer.

I have the following in place.  I'm clearing the interval on disconnect and also checking prior to setting the interval.  However, If I refresh the page a lot, it seems to not be accurate.  The console log will show 'time' in intervals much faster than one second and grouped together.

Any suggestions to ensure that a new timer never initiates more than once?

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Disconnected');
    clearInterval(timer);
}); 

if (typeof timer != 'undefined') {
    clearInterval(timer);
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('time');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You'd probably need to post more of your code for us to see the problem.

Comment: So... you only want to execute once... but you are using `setInterval` which is designed to execute a block of code... every interval.  Use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any suggestions to ensure that a new timer never initiates more than once?

That's exactly what `setTimeout()` does...

If perhaps you meant *"more than once **per second**"* you need to be aware that `setInterval()` will cause events to stack up if they're not handled in a timely fashion.  This will be what's causing your gaps of less than one second.

The only answer to that is to start a new one-shot timer using `setTimeout()` from within the timeout handler itself.   Calling `setTimeout` recursively within its own callback ensures that only one timer event at a time is ever put on the event queue.

Comment: Nope! `setTimeout` just executes once. And `setInterval` executes by each time period!

Comment: @PashaRumkin that's exactly my point.  The OP asked for something that **doesn't initiate more than once**.  `setTimeout()` initiates exactly once, and therefore satisfies that requirement.

Comment: Well I want it to continue every second, but I think I need to keep track of all the intervals running, so I can somehow make sure that setInterval is not called multiple times.  Not sure how a single setTimeout would elevate the problem or multiple setInterval's being called before the previous has been cleared - does that make sense?

Comment: @dave Why would you ever call `setInterval`? If you don't call it, you don't have to worry about it triggering again too quickly. What's wrong with @Alnitak's suggestion to just call `setTimeout` again from within the `setTimeout` handler?

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it, if I use setTimeout, with a setTimeout inside, it's the same essentially as using setInterval - It will continue every second (if that's what I have set).  When a disconnect/reconnect occurs in socket.io it will need to clear on disconnect and continue on connection.  This would put me in the same place, having to monitor how many times the setTimeout has run.

Comment: a recursive `setTimeout` is not the same as a `setInterval` because with `setTimeout` only one event will ever be queued at a time.  You haven't provided enough code for me to figure out how you want to mix your timeouts with your disconnects.

Answer (score -1):

Page reloading kills all timers. The problem is in browsers: when you create 1 second interval, and call `alert` Mozilla's SpiderMonkey interval event becomes 1 second after alert was **closed**, and Google's V8 run it 1 second after alert was **called**.
That's about different code flow organization in engines.

Comment: This timer isn't running in the browser, it's running on the node server